# Pick value based on key on object

Tags: javascript

```
var fields = {
    100: 'Harry',
    200: 'Zack'
};

var required = 200;
```

How can I get the output of Zack? I know there is a utility in lodash but not quite sure how to use it.

Comment: Is your real situation more complicated than this?  Lodash isn't necessary, just plain javascript should work: fields[required]

Comment: I suggest you go back and review a basic JS tutorial, which will help you understand how to access a property on an object. You could start [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**get**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#get):

```
var result = _.get(fields, required);
```

Comment: And how is this different/better than `fields[required]`?

Comment: OP asked about a Lodash solution.

Comment: But he doesn't need lodash.

Comment: The difference is `_.get(object, 'a.b.c', 'default')`, support for path and default value. But this is unnecessary complexity for the question asked, though it answers the question in terms of Lodash correctly.

Comment: You don't need lodash for anything as you could write everything in plain javascript. I did not presume that he could do without lodash as it may be a requirement to use it e.g an assignment.

Comment: So are you proposing that instead of writing `obj.a.b.c` he write `_.get(obj, 'a.b.c')`? That's insane. The tone of his question certainly does not suggest that using lodash is a requirement; it's fairly clear he doesn't know how to access properties on an object, and just imagines that he might need to use to lodash to do that.

Comment: The question is explicitly about lodash. It is tagged as lodash, it has lodash in the question text and heading. Not sure how you can suggest it's not.

Comment: Though overkill for OP, it's what he asked. The answer doesn't deserves a downvote. Downvote the question for a lack of research.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of plain Javascript.

```
var result = fields["200"]
```

or

```
var result = fields[required]
```

The important thing to note is that Javascript properties are internally stored as  string.

Answer (score 1):

fields[required] will work.

```
console.log(fields[required]);
```